# 380/220 vs 220/380

Tags: alternator

we just purchased a generator, and we hired a team to hook it up to our office, they recently encountered a problem when they tried to run the generator, it would generate 380V, instead of the 220V needed.

The voltage of our area is 220V (Philippines). I did my own research, and came across some generators with a voltage of 220/380V. So my question is, is 380/220V same as 220/380V? or are there any differences?

Generator(Cummins)/Alternator(Marathon) specs are 375Kva,380/220V,60Hz,1800Rpm, 3 phase,4 lines.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like a problem with how your team have wired up the motor.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-wye_transformer]
Source: http://www.electricalengineeringtoolbox.com/2014/08/electrical-power-in-3-phase-and-1-phase.html

It sounds like they have made a wye connection rather than a delta connection. Because if the motor is a 380/220. Then that means that it should be able to output 380 or 220 volt *. \$\frac{380}{220}\approx\sqrt3\$. And as you can see in the image above to the right, you are getting \$\sqrt3×220V\approx 380V\$

*I am pretty rusty regarding large motors, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yet, buildings are often line-neutral. Not delta.

Comment: But how do you get a neutral from a delta configuration?  Sounds like the generator will be unusable without a transformer.